# How to define namespaces

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have three XML files

**XML 1**

```
<h:table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html/">
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>
```

**XML 2**

```
<h:table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html2/">
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>
```

**XML 3**

```
<h:table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html3/">
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>
```

Depend on namespace in request I must switch between responses.
How to define namespace?

```
case namespace = <h:table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html/">:
    return "Response 1";
```

Comment: The issue is not clear from the question. When are you facing issue? And what are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by switch between the responses?

Answer (score 0):

You might use XmlHolder to iterate over DOM tree of the request. It provides method `getDomNode` to query an element by XPath. Then `getNamespaceURI` of the returned node provides the namespace string that you are looking for:

```
// create XmlHolder for request content
def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( mockRequest.requestContent )
// XPath search for the element and then match its namespace
switch (holder.getDomNode( "//h:table" ).getNamespaceURI()) {
    case ~/http:\/\/www.w3.org\/TR\/html\//:
        return "Response 1"
    case ~/http:\/\/www.w3.org\/TR\/html2\//:
        return "Response 2"
    case ~/http:\/\/www.w3.org\/TR\/html3\//:
        return "Response 3"
}
```